# reduce the code with Generic delegate or in other way

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Hello can you help me reduce code in C# I have many functions like these
I would like to reduce code for one function with parameter function which I will send later.

```
    public void WriteTransportCurrectCategoryTypes()
    {
        var jStr = GetJSONString("GetBusTypes");
        var jArr = JArray.Parse(jStr);
        var tTypes = new List<TransportCurrentCategoryType>();
        foreach (dynamic d in jArr)
        {
            var tType = new TransportCurrentCategoryType();
            ParseTransportCurrentCategoryType(tType, d);
            tTypes.Add(tType);
        }
    }

    public void WriteBusModelSpecs()
    {
        var jStr = GetJSONString("GetBusModelSpecs");
        var jArr = JArray.Parse(jStr);
        var specs = new List<Characteristic>();
        foreach (dynamic d in jArr)
        {
            var spec = new Characteristic();
            ParseBusModelSpecs(spec, d);
            specs.Add(spec);
        }
    }
```

I tryed to use delegate with Generic but It is not work

```
    public delegate void ParseParameters<T>(T objectClass,dynamic a);
    private static void ParceBusClass(BusClass busClass,dynamic a)
    {
        busClass.Name = a.Name;
        busClass.Transport = new TransportCategory {Id = a.BusModelCategoryId};
    }
```

then I call it:

```
     GetCollectionFromJSON<BusClass>("", ParceBusClass);
       private static List<T> GetCollectionFromJSON<T>(string functionName,                       ParseParameters<T> parseFunk){
    /****/
     parseFunk<T>(busClass, a);
    /***/
     }
```

It takes error,

Comment: Try `T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jStr)`

Comment: @I4V I can't do that because I have properties like this busClass.Transport = new TransportCategory {Id = a.BusModelCategoryId};

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can use the following:

```
public List<T> Write<T>(string name, Func<T> factory, Action<T, dynamic> parser)
{
    var jStr = GetJSONString(name);
    var jArr = JArray.Parse(jStr);
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (dynamic d in jArr)
    {
        var item = factory();
        parser(item, d);
        result.Add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
Write<Characteristic>(
    "GetBusModelSpecs", () => new Characteristic(), ParseBusModelSpecs);
Write<TransportCurrentCategoryType>(
    "GetBusTypes", () => new TransportCurrentCategoryType(),
    ParseTransportCurrentCategoryType);
```

If most or all of your classes have a default constructor, you can shorten this by providing an overload:

```
public List<T> Write<T>(string name, Action<T, dynamic> parser)
    where T : new()
{
    return Write<T>(name, () => new T(), parser);
}
```

Now you could call it like so:

```
Write<Characteristic>("GetBusModelSpecs", ParseBusModelSpecs);
Write<TransportCurrentCategoryType>(
    "GetBusTypes" ,ParseTransportCurrentCategoryType);
```

This answer doesn't take into account that there might exist a better way using your JSON library. See I4V's comment for an example.

Comment: thanks, but var item = factory(); doesn't work it writes that "Cannot resolve symbol factory"

Comment: @Abbath: Make sure you copied the code completely and don't have any typos. If you think you copied everything correctly, please upload a screenshot somewhere.

Comment: sorry mistake is main all works correctly thanks :) It was what I need

Answer (score 0):

Create generic abstract parent class `Writer` with [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for parsing json:

```
public abstract class Writer<T>        
{
    private readonly string _url;

    public Writer(string url)
    {
        _url = url;            
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        var jStr = GetJSONString(_url);
        var jArr = JArray.Parse(jStr);
        var tTypes = new List<T>();

        foreach (dynamic d in jArr)            
            tTypes.Add(Parse(d));           
        // other logic here            
    }

    protected abstract T Parse(object d); // implemented by concrete writers

    private string GetJSONString(string url)
    {
        // getting json string here
    }
}
```

Then create concreate child classes for each type you want to handle (they should specify url for loading JSON and override abstract Parse method):

```
public class TransportCurrectCategoryWriter : Writer<TransportCurrectCategory>
{
    public TransportCurrectCategoryWriter()
        : base("GetBusTypes")
    {
    }

    protected override TransportCurrectCategory Parse(object d)
    {
        // parse TransportCurrectCategory and return parsed instance
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var writer = new TransportCurrectCategoryWriter();
writer.Write();
```

No duplicated code. Easy to read and understand.